# React native: Strava Authentication goes to app?

Tags: react-native, strava

I am creating an react native app. How I linking from my app to strava app to authenticate to get the strava token to my app

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) package, which is well maintained and created by Formidable Labs. They have a docs page on adding authentication with Strava - https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/blob/main/docs/config-examples/strava.md